# Powershell to shut down a VM

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-2.0, powercli

I have a small Powershell script that is used to shut down my virtual machines in event of an extended power outage. It takes a specific VM object and forces a shutdown.

```
Function DirtyShutdown
{ param([VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Inventory.VirtualMachineImpl]$VM )
$VM | Stop-VM -Confirm:$false
}
```

I would like to speed up this process using the start-job command to run all these tasks in parallel. I have tried using several variants including the following which I believe to be correct.

```
Start-Job -InputObject $VM -ScriptBlock{ $input | Shutdown-VMGuest -Confirm:$false }
```

Based on the Receive-Job output it appears the problem is the snap in in use (added before the above function is called) is not loaded in the context of Start-Job.

What is the correct syntax to make this happen?

Comment: There's two answers to this, and I'll post them both and see what everyone likes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I appreciate the desire to use PowerShell v2's job subsystem for this task, note that vCenter has a built-in job system which you can take advantage of here. Most PowerCLI cmdlets which perform a change to your environment have a RunAsync parameter. To know which ones, run this piece of PowerShell code:

```
get-help * -parameter runasync
```

The RunAsync parameter will take your command(s) and queue them up in vCenter. The cmdlet will return a task object and then immediately return control back to your script.

To turn this into an answer in your case, simply append "-runasync" to the end of your Stop-VM command, like so:

```
$VM | Stop-VM -Confirm:$false -RunAsync
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was hoping for - I didn't see the RunAsync option in any of the documentation I reviewed and I was at this a couple hours. Days like this really make me miss Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you start a job, PowerShell creates a new runspace. This means a new environment that you may need to initialize, and that includes loading snap-ins and connecting to your VI Server. Start-Job has a parameter that you can use here called InitializationScript. Try something like this:

```
Start-Job -InitializationScript { Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core } {
    Connect-ViServer myserver
    Get-VM foo | Stop-VM
}
```

Comment: I actually couldn't get this to work; the job runs indefinitely. The syntax is sound, however, and you should see if it works for you. I've opened a thread with VMware engineering to see if this is a bug or just me.